# inheriting from a templates class with variable parameters

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

I have this code:

```
  template<char ...T>
  class base
  {
       std::array<uint8_t, ID_SIZE> m_ID = { Ts... };
  }

  template<char ...T>
  class derived: public base<T>
  {
       // this class doesn;t need to know anything about T
  }
```

when I compile this code, I am getting this error:

```
  'T': parameter pack must be expanded in this context
```

What is this error and how i can fix it?

Comment: You have to unpack the pack: `class derived: public base<T...>`

Comment: How do you expand the parameter pack in the `base` class (or in the `derived` class for that matter)? Have you tried something like that?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude add code that shows how data was unpacked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple template parameters (type or non-type) cannot be passed as packs but have to be unpacked each time:

```
template<char ...T>
class base { }

template<char ...T>
class derived: public base<T...> // unpack
{      
}
```

Inside of `base<>` the parameters will then be re-packed in the context of T.

Answer (score 2):

`T` is not one type, it is the name of a "parameter pack."

`base<T>` is nonsensical, because `base` requires a list of types, not a pack of types.  `base<T...>` will unpack the types and work as you expect.